# Is my thought process correct? Properties of an element $\omega$ of an intesection of infinite number of events

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1, A_2, ...$ be an infinite sequence of events.

Let $B_n = {\Large{\cap}}_{m=n}^\infty A_m$.

Let $B = {\Large{\cup}}_n B_n = {\Large{\cup}}_n {\Large{\cap}}_{m=n}^\infty A_m$.

The question (question 1.8.16 from the book "One Thousand Exercises in Probability") asks to show that:
$$B=\{\omega\in\Omega:\omega\in A_n \text{ for infinitely many values of n}\}$$

The given answer is:

$\omega \in B$ iff for all $n$, $\omega \in {\Large{\cup}}_n A_i$, that is $\omega$ belongs to infinitily many of the $A_n$.

I'm having trouble with understanding infinity here. My original intuition was that $\omega$ could just be in the 'last' of all the $A_n$'s. Now suppose $\omega \in B$. Is is correct that since we have infinitely many events, there is no 'last' event and that whenever we have an event $A_{k_1}$ for which $\omega \in A_{k_1}$ there are necessarily other events $A_{k_i}$ with $k_i > k_1$ and $\omega \in A_{k_i}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true for: $$\limsup A_n:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m$$ and not for: $$\liminf A_n:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m$$ It can happen that $\omega\in A_n$ for infinitely many $n$ and yet $\omega\notin\liminf A_n$. For instance let $\omega\in A_n$ if $n$ is odd and $\omega\notin A_n$ if $n$ is even. Then $\omega\notin\bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m$ for every $n$ and consequently $\omega\notin\liminf A_n$.

To prove (contrapositive) observe that the following statements are equivalent:

- $\omega\notin\limsup A_n$
- some $n$ exists with $\omega\notin\bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m$
- $\omega\notin A_m$ for $m=n,n+1,n+2,\dots$
- $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid\omega\in A_n\}$ is a finite set.

Comment: thanks a lot. the misstatement of the problem was indeed a typo